# how to scanf a string until a specific string is entered in C

Tags: c, string

I have been trying to write a code and a part of it is to scan multiple strings until it gets the 'Q' string. In this case the scanf should stop. 
How should I do it?
I have tried several ways, but none of them worked.

```
char array[100]={0};

while (flag == 1)
{
    scanf("%s", array);
    if(array == 'Q') {
       flag=0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the declaration of `array`? Perhaps you need `array[0] == 'Q'`

Comment: Change `scanf("%s", array);` to `scanf("%99s", array);` to prevent buffer overflow. Do the test `array[0] == 'Q'`

Comment: char array[100]={0};

Comment: You need to check the return value of `scanf` too.

Comment: You want to read about `strcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using the strcmp() function in the string.h library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char array[100] = {0};
    int flag = 1;

    while (flag == 1) {
        scanf("%s", array);

        if (!strcmp(array, "Q"))
                flag = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with this code

```
ch= getchar();
while( (ch != 'q' || ch !='Q') {
ch  = getchar();       
 putc(ch, fp);
   }
```

your mistake is here`scanf("%s", array);` it reads string and if condition you are checking without index of array variable
 you can check also by reading value with `scanf("%s", array); by looping value of array to find q in array

```
char a[100];
int i;
scanf("%c",&a[0]);
i=1;
while(a[i]!='q'&& a[i]='Q')
{

scanf("%c",&a[i]);
i++;
}
```

Comment: I am not allowed to do this with getchar

Comment: @Michelle check out now

Comment: You need to add bounds checking on the use of the array. Perhaps the use of `tolower`/`toupper`

Comment: @Michelle: if you are not allowed to use something, make sure to mention this in your question (and why). It helps getting answers that are useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

array[0] == 'Q'

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int flag = 1;
    char array[100]={0};

    while (flag == 1)
    {
        scanf("%s", array);
        if(array[0] == 'Q') {
           flag=0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why you are checking arr[0]=q i don't understand

Comment: jasinth  arr[0] == 0 because the author wants the 'Q' string. actually this gives any string starting by 'Q' if he wants the Q string then arr[0] == ''Q' && array[1] == 0.  I answered to solve the author mistake: arr == 0

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do, if you have to use `scanf()` (Notice the `%99s` to prevent buffer overflow -> 99 + `'\0'` == you buffer length)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char array[100]={0};
    do
    {
        scanf("%99s", array);
    } while (!(strlen(array) == 1 && array[0] == 'Q'));
}
```

[Online C Compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/HJV_FXgNM)